# Python BeautifulSoup extract suggested text entry (not visible in html)

Tags: python, input, beautifulsoup, extract

I am trying to extract a number from this website

http://www.mycryptobuddy.com/BitcoinMiningCalculator

[website and html picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwE6v.png)

I am trying to use beautifulsoup to extract this number in an input field where it says '3511.0' (shown in picture) however this is not visible in the html.

How am i able to extract this number with beautifulsoup?

my code:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'http://www.mycryptobuddy.com/BitcoinMiningCalculator'
page = request.urlopen(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
dif = soup.find('input', attrs={'ng-model': 'difficulty'})

print(dif.get('value'))
print(dif.attrs)
```

output:

```
None
{'type': 'number', 'ng-model': 'difficulty', 'ng-change': 'computeProfits(); turnAutoUpdateOff()'}
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: as you can see that value is being computed with the `computeProfits()`  method. It is an angular site. One way would be to use a Browser emulator to get those values, or you'll have to debug all the requests and the javascript code on how that value is calculated. Not an easy task.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't find this number in html is that it is not there, it's getting there by javascript receiving it through websocket located at ws://185.185.40.128:1235/socket.io/
as you can see on this picture: [image]

If you want to get those numbers, you should connect to that websocket, and parse incoming messages.